# assigning dynamically to document.getElementById from an array string

Tags: javascript

```
var urlName=new Array("total","pub");
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);

for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    document.getElementById("'"+urlName[i]+"'").innerHTML = pair[i];
}
```

How can I assign UrlNames dynamically?

Comment: i believe he has a bunch of urls ending in a number, ala urlName1, urlName2, urlName3 and he's trying to assign them.

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: Get rid of the quoted quotes, they can't be part of the id.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the quotes around `urlName[i]` since it's a string:

```
var urlName = ["total","pub"];

for (var i=0;i<urlName.length;i++) {
    document.getElementById(urlName[i]).innerHTML = pair[i];
}
```

Comment: im getting urlName[i] is null

Comment: @kiran: Then you did something else wrong that isn't in the code you showed us. Make a testcase that demonstrates your issue, and send us a link.

Comment: @kiran. I updated my code so that urlName[i] can't be NULL. I just realized you were loops until `vars.length` which might have been greater than 'urlName.length`. The only then that could be wrong in the above code is if your `pair` array isn't initialized properly.